# How to calculate the GDDR5 Capacity from this table?

Tags: dram

How to get 4Gb capacity from this table?

I understand it this way:

(1) total address is 14 + 6 + 4 = 24. each address (atom) is 32bit. So total capacity = 2^24 * 32bits = 512 Mbit.

I am not sure where is the 8x factor missing from the calculation.

Best,
Neo

[image: GDDR5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDDR5 uses an 8n-prefetch architecture.

Which basically means for a chip with 32-bit data bus is that with read or write commands, you can't (by default) access a single arbitrary 32-bit location, but a "block" of 8 concecutive locations of 32 bits in a burst.

So in short, internally the 4Gb chip can be thought to work with 16M addresses of 256 bits that are just accessed via a 32 bit external interface.